# How to turn on Campaign attribution in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales

How to turn on Campaign attribution to users?
What is  Campaign attribution in salesforce?
How we can use Campaign attributions in slaesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campaign Attribution (a.k.a. Campaign Influence) is a feature that allows the business to determine which marketing efforts are the most effective in growing the business, return on investment for marketing campaigns, and other related metrics. The process of setting this up is as simple as turning it on, adding the relevant related lists, and creating a model. Everything you need to know is located in the [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.campaigns_influence_customizable.htm&type=5).

Comment: Got it, Thanks @sfdcfox